# Cassandra Data Modelling and designing the Clustering

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, data-modeling, clustering-key

I am little confused on designing the data model for Cassandra, coming from SQL background! I have gone through `Datastax` documentation several times to understand many things about Cassandra! This seems to be problem and not sure how can I overcome this and type of data model which I should opt for!

[Primary Key along with Clustering](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html) is something really explained well here!
The documentation says that, Primary Key (Partition key, Clustering keys) is the most important thing in data model.

My use-case is pretty simple:

```
ITEM_ID    CREATED_ON     MOVED_FROM     MOVED_TO   COMMENT
```

`ITEM_ID` will be unique `(partition_key)` and each item might have 10-20 movement records! `I wanted to get the movement records of an item sorted by time it's created on.` So I decided go with `CREATED_ON` as clustering key.

According to documentation, clustering_key comes under secondary index which should be as much repeatable value as possible unlike partition key. My data-model exactly fails here! `How do I preserve order using clustering to achieve the same?`

Obviously I can't create some ID generation login in Application since it runs on many instances and if I have to relay on some logic, eventually the purpose of Cassandra goes for toss here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually do not need a secondary index for this particular example and secondary indexes are not created by default. Your clustering key all by itself will will allow you to do queries that look like

```
SELECT * from TABLE where ITEM_ID = SOMETHING;
```

Which will automatically give you back results sorted on your clustering key `CREATED_ON`.

The reason for this is your key will basically make partitions internally that looks like

```
ITEM_ID => [Row with first Created_ON], [Row with second Created_ON] ...
```

Comment: Doesn't Clustering column uses Secondary Index? or am I missing something? `primary key(itemid,created_on)`

Comment: It does not use a secondary index. A secondary index is a completely different concept.

Comment: this post and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168379/cassandra-choosing-a-partition-key are contradicting?? :-/ bit confused

Comment: Nope, I suggest you read through the answer again.

Specifically 
" In the primary key we have these components:

`PRIMARY KEY(partitioning key, clustering key_1 ... clustering key_n)`
"
The PRIMARY KEY is made up of a partitioning key and 0 or more clustering keys. 

These define the on disk layout of the data in the Cassandra table and are completely separate from the idea of secondary indexes.